# Program runs when launched by make, but not via shell, why?

Tags: c, debugging, unix, makefile

I wrote a C program in which I did some pretty heavy stack allocation, around 2 MiB. Since I use the poor man's IDE* I was automatically running the program via make in order to test it, each time I compiled.

I had pretty much wrapped everything up, but for some reason, during some of the final optimization, I ran it directly from the shell. Instant segfault! Running it with make still worked, and running it by hand always produced the same segfault.

I eventually reduced the amount of stack allocation I was doing to 256 KiB, which solved the problem. My rationale was that make was probably exec-ing the process, and thus it was inheriting some weird parameters that allowed it to use more stack space.

Although everything is fine now, I have no way of testing my theory. Can anyone confirm or deny, or suggest some way of testing?

* zsh, vim, gcc, gdb, and some nutty makefiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try setting the maximum stack size with [ulimit(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) and see if it works:

```
# Limit stack to 1024 KiB
ulimit -s 1024; ./myprogram
# Now no limit
ulimit -s unlimited; ./myprogram
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! It worked directly from the shell after 'ulimit -s unlimited'.

Man, seems like a kinda severe bug for a mature make program. (I'm using gmake 3.81) I guess I'll write them a friendly email :-)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug with make since it only failed outside of make: make was probably setting ulimit to a high (or unlimited) value for its own nefarious purposes and this was inherited by its subprocesses.

Comment: @pax, agreed. But, it seems to me that changing the environment that child processes inherit is still a bug. People do things like 'make test' all the time, and expect the fact that they're running through make not to affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my first step would be to try to locate where in the code the segfault occurred, either with gdb or debugging `printf`s or whatever. (This is why you always check return values from malloc, it cuts down on the possible sources of segfaults ;-p) For one thing, finding the exact source of the problem could give you evidence for or against your theory about stack allocation; also, it'll let you insert error-checking code so the program can exit gracefully with an informative error message rather than segfaulting.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to diagnose this.  Namely, it'd be nice to see the makefile and the shell scripts which you were using.